# Linux SSH: connect to existing console?

Tags: vnc, console

I know how to SSH into a Linux machine from a generic terminal.

My question is: Can I use a terminal only to display the contents on an existing console on the remote machine, ignoring my local keyboard input?

In other words:

Start a console session on A.  Use A's keyboard for that console session.  But use B's screen.

I realize VNC could accomplish this, but I'm looking for a pure console version.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest having a look at "[screen](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)".  As per [this page](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442418-using-screen-for-remote-interaction) it is possible to set a user as read only as your requirements suggest.

Comment: or tmux (which is screen on crack), and byobu (screen in a pretty dress)

Comment: +1 for this is an excellent suggestion (I use it regularly).  Note that it's sometimes also referred to as "GNU Screen."  (I also tried TMUX, which also seems quite good and also uses different keystrokes so you can use the two of them together; +1 for @crasic's comment too).  With these solutions you can "detach" from the console, logout, then connect again later with a new SSH session (even from an entirely different site), and "re-attach" to continue where you left off.